# Using Firebase's reserved hosted URLs for local flutter development

Tags: firebase-hosting, flutter-web, firebase-tools

I'm developing an app in flutter and deploying it to Firebase hosting.

Firebase hosting and the `firebase serve` command for local development let you initialize Firebase from a special auto-generated relative URL (`/__/firebase/init.js`).

This is nice because it allows me to share my project (on github, for example) without including my Firebase configuration.

Sadly, this does not seem to play nice with `flutter run` -- if I use `flutter run`, I lose the special URLs, and if I use `firebase serve`, I lose flutter's hot reload features.

My current workaround is to have the following local files under my `app/web/` directory:

```
  __/firebase/init.js                   # containing firebase.initializeApp(myFirebaseConfig);
  __/firebase/7.1.44/firebase-app.js    # manually downloaded from the gstatic cdn
  __/firebase/7.1.44/firebase-auth.js
  # ... (etc)
```

This works, but:

- The `__` directory actually gets deployed to Firebase. (Not actually a problem, but it seems wrong)
- It's annoying to set this up manually in each local development environment.

Ideally, one should be able to `firebase login`, `firebase init`, and then `flutter serve`, and then automagically have access to the `/__/` directory.

Is there already some way to make this happen, and if not, how could we implement it?

(For example, is there a way to extend flutter's local http server to take advantage of the logic that's already in the `firebase-tools` npm module?)

Comment: I have the same problem -- did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, just sticking with the above workaround for now. :/

Comment: According to the [firebase docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web), this is not possible yet: "We are actively investigating ways to initialize Firebase without directly using the CDN and will update the documentation once this becomes available." So for now they say just use the gstatic links.

Comment: I am not getting the Automatic option now when adding a web app in the firebase project. Does someone know any fix?